# I need a fresh pair of airs for this error here: "undefined method `items' for #<Order:0x00007f93d361b390>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Ruby and building a shopping cart site, for book.

I am trying to create my orders. Was following the tutorial below.

```html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orDmqI-dlCo&list=PLebos0ZZRqzeT7XBTYwL9JGN1PwoZVB9p&index=4
```

The Error happens when I click on Add order to basket, the problem is that "items" is only referrenced on the routes and not on the tables, I have order_items table in my schema, I must be tired, but if you can help will appreciate.

```
book = Book.find(book_id)

order_item = order.items.find_or_create_by(
  book_id: book_id
)
```

Order Items Controller

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    current_bag.add_item(
      book_id: params[:book_id],
      quantity: params[:quantity]
    )

    redirect_to bag_path
  end
end
```

Shopping Bag Controller

```
class ShoppingBag
  def initialize(token:)
    @token = token
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.find_or_create_by(token: @token) do | order|
      order.sub_total = 0
    end
  end

  def add_item(book_id:, quantity: 1)
    book = Book.find(book_id)

    order_item = order.items.find_or_create_by(
      book_id: book_id
    )

    order_item.price = book.price
    order_item.quantity = quantity

    order_item.save
  end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "books#index"

  resources :line_items
  get '/bag', to: 'order_items#index'
  resources :order_items, path: '/bag/items'

  # resources :locations
  resources :books

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
  resources :pricing, only: [:index]
  resources :subscriptions
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

My Order.rb file

```html
class Order < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Comment: Does `Order` have a `has_many :items` relationship or not?

Comment: I don't have that relationship in my orders, "items", should I have "has _many  :order_items" since I don't have an "items" table, only reference I have for "items" is on the routes. ( I am a newbie here)

Comment: Could you add your `Order` class to to the question? We don't need all of it, only the class definition and associations.

Comment: What is “order”? What does “order.inspect” show?

Comment: It shows this  "Order(id: integer, sub_total: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, token: string)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial probably added the needed associations between the first and second video ([like mentioned in part 1 timestamp 36:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwoafJC7vlw&list=PLebos0ZZRqzeT7XBTYwL9JGN1PwoZVB9p&index=1&t=36m20s)).

With your current code I would assume they are as follows:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, class_name: 'OrderItem'
  # ...
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  # ...
end
```

For this to work the `order_items` table must have an `order_id` column (with the same type as the `id` column of the `orders` table).

For more info about associations check out the [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide.